# How to customize a website only for webview

Tags: php, android, html

I have an Android application which is a webview. How can I determine in html/php that my website is accessed exclusive from WebView in order to personize things?

Answer (score 0):

Use a get param appended to the URL like https://www.xxx.yyy/link/url/details?personId=34

Now your server can read `$_GET['personId']` and check who the person is coming into this link. Person with id 34 in the above case.

You can also use a key as you like to determine if this is WebView. Say something like this:

https://www.xxx.yyy/link/url/details?isWebView=1&personId=34

Now your server can read if `isWebView` = 1 then you know its coming from a WebView

There are other ways to find what type of a client the request is coming from using server variables in PHP `$_SERVER`